# Firebase Google Analitycs and Google Ads Analitycs require to load gtag twice

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I use firebase analytics on my website with the usual config and want to connect my analytics to google ads.

I use `measurementId` for firebase analytics but google ads require me to use UA-XXX `propertyId` and require me to add an additional tag.

Questions:

1. Can I use existing property for google analytics that starts with G-XX?
2. Do I really need to load gtag.js twice?
3. One for firebase analytics and the second for google ads analytics?